# Quantifying the baryon asymmetry requires normalizing the baryon number density w.r.t comoving entropy density or photon density-Why?

Tags: cosmology, antimatter, beyond-the-standard-model, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

**This question has been edited a little to clarify the confusion I have.**

The *matter-antimatter asymmetry* of the Universe quantified by the *baryon asymmetry* as
$$Y_B=\frac{n_B-n_{\bar{B}}}{s}=\frac{n_B}{s}$$
i.e., the difference in the number densities of baryons $n_B$ and antibaryons $n_{\bar{B}}$ normalized w.r.t the *comoving entropy density* $s$. Sometimes the baryon assymetry is also expressed by normalizin the baryon number density w.r.t the comoving photon density $n_\gamma$.

<strike>*What is the significance of normalizing the baryon asymmetry w.r.t $s$? Does it have anything to do with the fact that $sa^3$ is conserved (where $a$ is the scale factor)?*</strike>

**Addendum** *Why is it that people don't quote simply $(n_B-n_{\bar{B}})$ i.e., the number density of baryons (more precisely, that of baryons minus antibaryons) as the baryon asymmetry? Why do we have to normalize it w.r.t either the photon density $n_\gamma$  or the entropy density $s$?*

*I understand that as the Universe expands, this number density dilutes. Does it mean that the normalized quantity $Y_B$ don't dilute? If yes, is this the reason for normalizing it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to normalize it to *something* because $n_B - n_\bar B$ is just the number of baryons in the universe.
I more frequently see the baryon asymmetry normalized by the number of CMB photons (e.g. [this PDG table](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2016-rev-astrophysical-constants.pdf).

The Particle Data Group's review of [Big-Bang cosmology](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2017/reviews/rpp2016-rev-bbang-cosmology.pdf) says on page 12

> For photons [...]
>   $$
> d(sR^3)/dt = 0.
> $$
>   For radiation, this corresponds to the relationship between expansion and cooling, $T \propto R^{-1}$ in an adiabatically expanding universe.
>   Note also that both $s$ and $n_\gamma$ scale as $T^3$.

I interpret this to mean that your entropy-scaled baryon asymmetry and my photon-scaled baryon asymmetry are simply proportional to one another, for just the reason that you guessed in your question.

Comment: It's the "Addendum" that captures my confusion better. @rob

Comment: @SRS A number density would change as the Universe expands, but a ratio of number densities should not.